# Internal HDD not showing up anymore

Tags: hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery, hard-drive-failure

One of my internal hard disks(out of 3) stopped showing up in Disk management(Windows) or Disks(Ubuntu). Its showing up in BiOS.

These are what i could find from ubuntu terminal:

"sdc is the one not showing up"

```
desktop:~$ ls /dev/ |grep sd
sda
sda1
sda2
sda3
sdb
sdb1
sdb2
sdb5
sdb6
sdb7
sdc
sdc1
sdc2
sdc5
sdc6
```

```
desktop:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 149.1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  19.1G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0   8.6G  0 part /home
└─sda3   8:3    0 121.4G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0    50G  0 part 
├─sdb2   8:18   0     1K  0 part 
├─sdb5   8:21   0   120G  0 part 
├─sdb6   8:22   0   120G  0 part 
└─sdb7   8:23   0 175.8G  0 part 
sdc      8:32   0 149.1G  0 disk 
├─sdc1   8:33   0    44G  0 part 
├─sdc2   8:34   0     1K  0 part 
├─sdc5   8:37   0   4.1G  0 part 
└─sdc6   8:38   0   101G  0 part
```

The same command later gave output without sdc

```
desktop:~$ lsblk -f | grep sd
sda                                                             
├─sda1 ext4                e08571b3-42e5-47c4-b205-424ced070577 /
├─sda2 ext4                f31cc5af-5320-4a85-99c7-13290c7b8037 /home
└─sda3 ntfs     New Volume EA2426C024268F9D                     
sdb                                                             
├─sdb1 ntfs                620CE1210CE0F0C9                     
├─sdb2                                                          
├─sdb5 ntfs                01CC3697A2177670                     
├─sdb6 ntfs                01CC3697A82C5120                     
└─sdb7 ntfs                01CC3697AE116940
```

```
desktop:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 2.3 MiB, 2433024 bytes, 4752 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 3.7 MiB, 3887104 bytes, 7592 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 140.9 MiB, 147722240 bytes, 288520 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 14.5 MiB, 15196160 bytes, 29680 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 86.9 MiB, 91099136 bytes, 177928 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 13 MiB, 13619200 bytes, 26600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 34.7 MiB, 36323328 bytes, 70944 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 149.1 GiB, 160040803840 bytes, 312579695 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x92305b46

Device     Boot    Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        2048  39999487  39997440  19.1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       39999488  57999359  17999872   8.6G 83 Linux
/dev/sda3       57999360 312573951 254574592 121.4G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


Disk /dev/sdb: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xfdc73bf7

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *           63 104856254 104856192    50G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2       104856255 976735934 871879680 415.8G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdb5       104856318 356514479 251658162   120G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb6       356514543 608172704 251658162   120G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb7       608172768 976735934 368563167 175.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


desktop:~$ dmesg | tail -n 20
[  876.033528] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[  876.033546] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  876.033548] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 80 00 00 08 00
[  876.033549] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 128
[  876.033551] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 16, async page read
[  876.033567] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1235.918270] scsi_io_completion: 5 callbacks suppressed
[ 1235.918276] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 1235.918280] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1235.918281] print_req_error: 5 callbacks suppressed
[ 1235.918282] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0
[ 1235.918304] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 1235.918307] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1235.918308] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0
[ 1235.918310] buffer_io_error: 4 callbacks suppressed
[ 1235.918311] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1235.918333] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 1235.918335] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1235.918336] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0
[ 1235.918338] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
```

And finally

```
desktop:~$ sudo e2fsck -fv /dev/sdc
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
e2fsck: Input/output error while trying to open /dev/sdc

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

dmesg right after boot:

```
desktop:~$ dmesg | grep sdc
[    5.539169] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] 312581808 512-byte logical blocks: (160 GB/149 GiB)
[    5.539179] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[    5.539180] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    5.539197] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    5.774696]  sdc: sdc1 sdc2 < sdc5 sdc6 >
[    5.775059] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[   10.311689] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[   10.311694] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[   10.311698] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[   10.311702] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 80 00 01 80 00
[   10.311704] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 395
[   16.367270] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[   16.367274] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[   16.367278] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[   16.367281] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 01 88 00 00 08 00
[   16.367283] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 395
[   16.367288] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 49, async page read
[   19.540830] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[   19.540833] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[   19.540837] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[   19.540841] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 01 88 00 00 08 00
[   19.540843] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 395
[   19.540846] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 49, async page read
[   25.396513] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[   25.396518] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[   25.396521] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[   25.396525] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 06 01 79 3f 00 01 80 00
[   25.396528] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 100760064
[   29.153139] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[   29.153142] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[   29.153145] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[   29.153149] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 bf 00 01 80 00
[   29.153151] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 395
[   33.659433] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[   33.659436] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[   33.659440] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[   33.659444] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 06 01 79 ff 00 00 08 00
[   33.659447] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 100760064
[   33.659451] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc6, logical block 321, async page read
[   33.659454] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc6, logical block 322, async page read
[   33.659457] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc6, logical block 323, async page read
[   33.659460] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc6, logical block 324, async page read
[   33.659462] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc6, logical block 325, async page read
[   33.659465] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc6, logical block 326, async page read
[   33.659468] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc6, logical block 327, async page read
[   36.524795] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[   36.524799] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[   36.524802] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[   36.524806] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 06 01 7a 00 00 00 01 00
[   36.524808] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 100760064
[   36.524812] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc6, logical block 321, async page read
[   40.647926] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[   40.647930] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[   40.647933] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[   40.647937] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 06 01 7a 02 00 00 05 00
[   40.647939] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 100760066
[   40.647949] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc6, logical block 323, async page read
[   40.647952] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc6, logical block 324, async page read
[   40.647955] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc6, logical block 325, async page read
[   40.647958] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc6, logical block 326, async page read
[   40.647960] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc6, logical block 327, async page read
[   44.038059] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[   44.038062] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[   44.038066] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[   44.038069] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 01 87 00 00 08 00
[   44.038072] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 395
[   44.038075] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 332, async page read
[   44.038078] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 333, async page read
[   44.038081] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 334, async page read
[   44.038084] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 335, async page read
[   47.828004] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[   47.828007] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[   47.828011] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[   47.828014] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 01 8b 00 00 01 00
[   47.828016] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 395
[   47.828020] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 332, async page read
[   65.528327] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[   65.528331] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[   65.528334] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[   65.528339] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 80 00 01 80 00
[   65.528341] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 395
[   70.834279] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[   70.834284] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[   70.834288] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[   70.834292] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 01 88 00 00 08 00
[   70.834295] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 395
[   70.834302] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 49, async page read
[   73.916203] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[   73.916208] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[   73.916211] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[   73.916216] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 01 88 00 00 08 00
[   73.916218] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 395
[   73.916225] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 49, async page read
[   79.097188] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[   79.097192] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[   79.097195] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[   79.097201] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 06 01 79 3f 00 01 80 00
[   79.097203] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 100760064
[   84.494738] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[   84.494742] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[   84.494746] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[   84.494750] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 4f 00 00 08 00
[   84.494753] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 81
[   88.101432] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[   88.101436] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[   88.101440] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[   88.101445] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 bf 00 01 80 00
[   88.101447] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 395
[   91.533227] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[   91.533231] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[   91.533235] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[   91.533239] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 4f 00 00 08 00
[   91.533242] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 81
[   91.533249] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 18, async page read
[   91.533253] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 19, async page read
[   91.533256] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 20, async page read
[   91.533259] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 21, async page read
[   91.533262] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 22, async page read
[   91.533265] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 23, async page read
[   94.581832] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[   94.581837] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[   94.581840] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[   94.581846] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 51 00 00 06 00
[   94.581848] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 81
[   94.581854] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 18, async page read
[   94.581859] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 19, async page read
[   94.581862] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 20, async page read
[   94.581865] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 21, async page read
[   98.180212] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[   98.180216] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[   98.180220] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[   98.180224] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 06 01 79 ff 00 00 08 00
[   98.180227] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 100760064
[   98.180234] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc6, logical block 321, async page read
[   98.180238] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc6, logical block 322, async page read
[   98.180241] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc6, logical block 323, async page read
[   98.180245] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc6, logical block 324, async page read
[   98.180248] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc6, logical block 325, async page read
[   98.180251] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc6, logical block 326, async page read
[   98.180254] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc6, logical block 327, async page read
[  100.545810] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  100.545814] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[  100.545817] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[  100.545822] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 06 01 7a 00 00 00 01 00
[  100.545825] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 100760064
[  100.545832] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc6, logical block 321, async page read
[  103.336213] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  103.336217] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[  103.336220] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[  103.336225] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 06 01 7a 02 00 00 05 00
[  103.336227] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 100760066
[  103.336234] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc6, logical block 323, async page read
[  103.336238] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc6, logical block 324, async page read
[  103.336242] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc6, logical block 325, async page read
[  103.336245] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc6, logical block 326, async page read
[  103.336248] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc6, logical block 327, async page read
```

Any help will be appreciated. I would really like to get my data back.

Comment: Have you tried running e2fsck? How old is the disk? Add to the post [SMART[(https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools) data and test results. Check all disk connections and try another connector cable. It's also possible that the disk had a hardware issue and is now dead.

Answer (score 1):

The most common reason for this is bad connection. Try to unplug the disk, change the data cable and plug it into a different port, or plug it in a different computer. Unless your computer was hit by lightning which fried the onboard electronics, there is a good chance that everything is still OK.

If it still doesn't work, post a larger chunk of dmesg. Also check if BIOS sees the disk.

**EDIT:** From the additional information you posted it looks that disk is indeed bad - not a connection problem, but unreadable sectors.

Comment: Thanks you gave me some hope :D
Tried changing ports and cables and all.It's definitely not lightning. It has something to do with me playing around with disk management(Don't remember what)
Yes it is detected in bios too

Comment: Post `dmesg | grep sdc`. The interesting part is usually at the beginning, right after boot.

Comment: I have added it to end of description

Answer (score -2):

Make sure the drive is connected properly. Disconnect and reconnect it. Try different motherboard ports and PSU plugs.

If it still doesn't show up, it's dead. That's time to dust off your backups. If you don't have backups, you'll have to pay some good money for professional data recovery services.

Comment: Downvoter, please explain what's wrong with this answer and how it should be improved. Downvoting without a comment will keep it bad forever.